# How to split strings inside of an array in JavaScript (to get first names from full names)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, foreach, split

My assignment is to print the first names of all individuals from a data set that fit a specific category; however, the data set is an array of objects that provides the full name as a string, e.g.:

```
var dataSet = [ 
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 60,
        "math": 97,
        "english": 63,
        "yearsOfEducation": 4
    },
    {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "age": 55,
        "math": 72,
        "english": 96,
        "yearsOfEducation": 10
    }
]
```

I cannot use any array type built-in functions except filter(), map(), and reduce().

The last chunk of my code (to get names from the array of objects "dataSet") looks like:

```
var youngGoodMath = dataSet.filter(function(person){
    return person.age < avgAge && person.math > avgMath;
  });

  var yGMname = youngGoodMath.map(function (person){
    return person.name;
  });

console.log(yGMname);
```

which produces an array of strings that looks something like:

```
["Jane Doe", "John Doe", "Harry Potter", "Hermione Granger"]
```

I need to find a way to produce:

```
["Jane", "John", "Harry", "Hermione"]
```

I suspect the answer lies in using .forEach and .Split(), but haven't been able to crack it yet...

Comment: Split on space, return first element  ... `return person.name.split(' ')[0]`

Comment: When I first started programming, Jane was about 23 :D Thanks for keeping their age current lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your map function try var names = person.name.split(" "); and return names[0];

Comment: That does it! @charlietfl said the same thing slightly rephrased above in the comments: "Split on space, return first element ... return person.name.split(' ')[0]" Both work great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to solve this. Basically, you need to map every `fullname` to the `first name`, so using `split` by `space` character on every `fullname` we can get an array of names, and the first element of that array will be the `first name`.

```js
const input = ["Jane Doe", "John Doe", "Harry Potter", "Hermione Granger"];

let res =  input.map(name =>
{
    [first, ...rest] = name.split(" ");
    return first;
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Another alternative is to use [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regular expression, i.e, match a starting sequence of characters that are followed by a `space`.

```js
const input = ["Jane Doe", "John Doe", "Harry Potter", "Hermione Granger"];
let res =  input.map(name => name.match(/^.*(?=\s)/)[0]);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: One-liner: `input.map(x => x.split(' ')[0])`

Answer (score 0):

in case you are allowed to use the `forEach` property, you might want to:

```
dataSet.forEach( function( x ) { console.log( x.name.match( /\w+/)+"" ) } );
```

otherwise you'll have to learn how to use the `while` loop.